# How to write a number in type float?

Tags: c#, floating-point, binary

I have the following problem to solve in C#:
Write a number such as 1066018.050 in type float,
the result should be in binary or hexadecimal format.
My question is what are the correct steps I need to follow in order to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BitConverter.GetBytes(float)`.

```
float a = (1066018.050F);
var b = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
```